# WSO2 EMM: How to enrol multiple Android devices in one go?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I've gone through the documentation of enrolling device one by one using this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM330/Android).

Also I can see that there is another way to do it by calling API from each mobile as [given](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS320/swagger/?url=https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS320/swagger/android.json#!/Android_Device_Management/enrollDevice). The description of the same mentions that `Instead, you can use this REST API to register an Android device with WSO2 IoT Server, without having to install an Android Agent.`

But is there any way to enrol multiple devices in one shot ? Let's say I want to enrol all the android devices which are in my network, something like that ?

Because if company has around 2000 employees, it's useless to call API from each mobile (which will be the manual process) or by downloading Download IoT Server Agent on each mobile and following steps given in [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM330/Android+Device).

Let me know what strategy we can use to solve this problem ? or I'm missing something from documentation of WSO2-EMM which already solves this problem.

Comment: Is you end objective here is to bulk enroll large number of Android devices at once or to do a load test by enrolling devices via API calls?

Comment: Objective is to enroll large number of Android devices at once. If I take this application and planning to integrate in some xyz company, then something like this has to be there, right ?

Comment: I am looking for the same, can you let us know if you found a solution please.

Comment: Also the documentation link seems to be dead.